# Should I use AddMvc or AddMvcCore for ASP.NET Core MVC development?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC from a book, the code snippet in question is as follows:

```
// CHAPTER 4 - ESSENTIAL C# FEATURES
namespace LanguageFeatures {

    public class Startup {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // etc.
```

Because the book is about ASP.NET Core MVC rather than ASP.NET MVC, I think I  have to use `AddMvcCore()` rather than `AddMvc()` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore(); // as opposed to:
    //services.AddMvc();
}
```

Is what I do here correct?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Have a look at the [`MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26) class on the [ASP.NET Core GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore):

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddMvc(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    var builder = services.AddMvcCore();

    builder.AddApiExplorer();
    builder.AddAuthorization();

    AddDefaultFrameworkParts(builder.PartManager);

    // Order added affects options setup order

    // Default framework order
    builder.AddFormatterMappings();
    builder.AddViews();
    builder.AddRazorViewEngine();
    builder.AddRazorPages();
    builder.AddCacheTagHelper();

    // +1 order
    builder.AddDataAnnotations(); // +1 order

    builder.AddCors();

    return new MvcBuilder(builder.Services, builder.PartManager);
}
```

`AddMvcCore()` and `AddMvc()` both return an `IMvcBuilder` that can be used to further configure the MVC services.

`AddMvcCore()`, as the name implies, only adds core components of the MVC pipeline, requiring you to add any other middleware (needed for your project) by yourself.

`AddMvc()` internally calls `AddMvcCore()` and adds other middleware such as the Razor view engine, Razor pages, CORS, etc.

For now, I would follow what your tutorial suggests and stick to `AddMvc()`.

---

As of ASP.NET Core 3.0, there are additional methods that give fine-grained control over what portions of the MVC pipeline are available to your application, e.g.:

- [`services.AddControllers()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addcontrollers?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_MvcServiceCollectionExtensions_AddControllers_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_)
- [`services.AddControllersWithViews()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addcontrollerswithviews?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_MvcServiceCollectionExtensions_AddControllersWithViews_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_)

Refer to [this article](https://www.strathweb.com/2020/02/asp-net-core-mvc-3-x-addmvc-addmvccore-addcontrollers-and-other-bootstrapping-approaches/) and MSDN for more information about what they do and when to use them.