# What is the difference between AddMVC, AddMvcCore and AddRouting in ASP NETCore

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for performance improvement in my ASP.net Core project
I am using graphql.net instead of REST  in my project. So I don't need MVC mostly. But I also have a health check endpoint lets say api/health to check the service health. For that I need to add MVC to my application.

Initially I was using the `addMVC` extension, later I figured out that I should use `addMVCCore` instead of add `addMVC` to exclude unnecessary bundle.

Today I came across this article 
https://hackernoon.com/iris-go-vs-net-core-kestrel-in-terms-of-http-performance-806195dc93d5

It talks about using `AddRouting` alone and using kestrel

I am already using kestrel.

I wanted to know what exactly differs among the three.
Can I use `addRouting` instead of `addMVCCore` if I just need a health check endpoint ? would that improve perf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use AddMvc or AddMvcCore for ASP.NET Core MVC development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097229/should-i-use-addmvc-or-addmvccore-for-asp-net-core-mvc-development)

Comment: I am aware of the above thread, but I also want to know about addrouting part 
Is that enough with kestrel

Answer (score 0):

AddMVC() internally calls the AddMVCCore() .

AddMVC() calls the required services for the MVC .  like return view() from the action and it has only the minimum dependencies required to run the MVC framework

addMvcCore() calls only the mvc core services . it contains the return content("") and it doesn't contains the dataannotations ,auth filters , cors filter .

Comment: No mention of addRouting