# What is the difference between AddAuthentication and AddAuthenticationCore?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

Looking at the code for [AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAuthentication()](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) vs [AuthenticationCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAuthenticationCore()](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Authentication.Core/src/AuthenticationCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), it looks like AddAuthentication implicitly calls AddAuthenticationCore, adds some other goodies, and then returns a new instance of AuthenticationBuilder instead of just returning IServiceCollection.

Am I understanding the code correctly?  If so, are there generally any reasons to call AddAuthenticationCore instead of AddAuthentication outside of writing your own extension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be a typical pattern in ASP.NET Core: the `Add[xxx]Core` methods add the bare minimum to enable a feature, but without any bells and whistles. It's also probably used to make unit testing the core features easier.

You can make a parallel with the `AddMvc` vs `AddMvcCore` methods. There's a question that asks [Should I use AddMvc or AddMvcCore for ASP.NET Core MVC development?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40097229/2698119), and the gist is that it allows for fine-grained control on what middleware you want to use.

To answer your question: for a typical user, there's probably no reason to use  `AddAuthenticationCore`.

Comment: Interesting.  That's the impression I got from reading the code, so it's good to see it backed up by this blog post linked in the answer you linked (the author of which appears to be an MVP and works on Omnisharp):  https://www.strathweb.com/2020/02/asp-net-core-mvc-3-x-addmvc-addmvccore-addcontrollers-and-other-bootstrapping-approaches/

Comment: That is not answering the question!

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a reason. Currently `AddAuthentication()` also adds data protection services, which you may not need - for example if you are writing your own Authentication Scheme. So instead you can do this:

```
services.AddAuthenticationCore(o => {
    o.DefaultScheme = "My Custom Scheme";
});
services.AddWebEncoders();
services.AddSingleton<ISystemClock, SystemClock>();
var authBuilder = new AuthenticationBuilder(services);
```

however I fully expect this to break in future versions of asp.net core as it's undocumented and a bit of a hack.